# Switching to next select field by class of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

This emulates behavior of <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> with <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd>.

I.e., switch focus to the next/previous `select` field with parent class `.tab` (which are not siblings in the DOM.)

It works, but is there any way to make it more elegant? Especially the `if`/`then` and the limit to range. I'm fairly new to JavaScript.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.tab select', function (e) {
    let tabs = $(".tab select");                        //get all tabs
    let tab = tabs.index($($(document.activeElement))); //focused tab
    if (e.which == 37) {                                //left arrow
        tab -= 1;
    } else {
        if (e.which == 39) {                            //right arrow
            tab += 1;
        }
    };
    tab = Math.min(tabs.length, Math.max(tab, 0));      //stay in range
    tabs.eq(tab).focus()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could consider is making this a little more generic and thus reusable. Currently you seem to assume, that there is only one `.tab` element in your document. If you had multiple (independent) `.tab` elements, each with their own set of `select` elements and you did't want to allow "tabbing" between then, then `$(".tab select")` will select all selects and not only the ones in the "current" `.tab`. So instead of

```
let tabs = $(".tab select");
```

I'd use

```
let tabs = $(this).closest(".tab").find("select");
```

Furthermore instead of hardcoding the selectors, consider making them variable, so that the script could be used with other class names and form elements:

```
function initArrowKeyTabbing(parentSelector, formElementSelector) {
  $(document).on('keydown', parentSelector + " " + formElementSelector, function (e) {
    $(this).closest(parentSelector).find(formElementSelector);
    // ...
  }
}

initArrowKeyTabbing(".tab", "select");
```

---

In the line

```
let tab = tabs.index($($(document.activeElement)));
```

you are calling `jQuery` twice. `tabs.index($(document.activeElement))` would suffice. For the matter of the fact, `.index()` alternatively takes a DOM element as its parameter, so you even only need `tabs.index(document.activeElement)`.

---

With an `if ... else if ...` construct you don't need the brackets around the second if:

```
if (e.which == 37) {
    tab -= 1;
} else if (e.which == 39) {
    tab += 1;
}
```

In this case instead of using `if`, a `switch` statement would be more flexible:

```
switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
       tab--; // Short form of tab -= 1;
       break;
    case 39:
       tab++;
       break;
}
```

---

The `which` event property is deprecated. The "proper" replacement is the `key` property, which however requires concessions towards IE and Edge, which use non-standard key names:

```
switch (e.key) {
  case "Left": // IE/Edge specific value
  case "ArrowLeft":
    tab--;
    break;
  case "Right": // IE/Edge specific value
  case "ArrowRight":
    tab++;
    break;
}
```

Comment: I understood from the `(which are not siblings in the DOM)` that the OP wants tabbing between all `.tab select`’s.

Comment: @morbusg Yes, but as i understand it, all `select`s all inside the same `tab`. That `tab` element isn't really necessary, if the script should apply to all `select`s on the page, however if there are multiple `tab` elements, the "tabbing" could be "isolated" to each `tab`.